# MySQL character set CLI and Workbench show different results

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, character-set

[image]

**Q: Character sets shown by the MySQL CLI command lines and my MySQL workbench show different results. Why is that?**

I've run into MySQL 'chcp' error and cannot view my server status after updating my MySQL workbench, current version is 8.0.27. So after searching up some google have found out it's MySQL Workbench bug dealing with other non-Engligsh languages and I've found out some solutions which were to have System variable Path include System32 and MySQL bin folder which are included well to my system path variable. Other solutions were to change my system language to English, or either check to using UTF-8 in my system locale settings. But the first solution would be very inconvenient for me to use my computer and the second solution made my console applications not able to handle non-English characters. The final solution I've found was to change the C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0\workbench\os_utils.py the internal code

`process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, encoding="utf-8", stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)`

from utf-8 to other codepage. But I'm anxious that that would occur other internal bugs so I haven't tried it yet.

**Q: Are there any alternative solution to this "chcp" error? except for downgrading the workbench?**

[image]

Comment: This belongs to dba.stackexchange.com not to S.O.

Comment: go to file C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 6.3 CE\modules open this file wb_admin_export.py. and change default-character-set and save file then reconnect to db

Comment: Also In MySQL Workbench (8.0), you can click the Administration tab, select Options File under Instance, scroll to the International section and you'll find character-set-server and collation-server, which you can set to your desired charset and collation. Click the Apply button to save the changes.

Comment: Do you want utf8mb4 so that you can handle all character sets?  Or do you want to be limited to euckr (roughly speaking, just Korean and English).  What are the settings in Workbench, the OS, and my.cnf?